# Adding data using SQLite in android studio

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Im new at android development and this is my first android app using SQLite by following a tutorial but i get error "main java.lang.NullPointerException" when inserting. here is my code:

This is my activity_main.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.xperiasola.philubiq64wi.xperiasola.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etSurname"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Sname"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etName"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etMarks"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Marks"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etSurname"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btAdd"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etMarks"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is my DatabaseHelper.java code:

```
package com.xperiasola.philubiq64wi.xperiasola;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

/**
 * Created by philUbiq64wi on 1/26/2018.
 */

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "student.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "tbl_user";
    public static final String COLUMN_1 = "ID";
    public static final String COLUMN_2 = "NAME";
    public static final String COLUMN_3 = "SURNAME";
    public static final String COLUMN_4 = "MARKS";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {

        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

        String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +
                " ( " + COLUMN_1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                COLUMN_2 + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_3 + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_4 + " TEXT )";


        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }

    public boolean insertData(String name, String surname, String marks) {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_2, name);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_3, surname);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_4, marks);

        long result;
        result = sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }


    }
}
```

This is my MainActivty.java code:

```
package com.xperiasola.philubiq64wi.xperiasola;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseHelper myDb;
    private static Button btAdd;
    private static EditText etName, etSurname, etMarks;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btAdd = findViewById(R.id.btAdd);
        etName = findViewById(R.id.etName);
        etSurname = findViewById(R.id.etSurname);
        etMarks = findViewById(R.id.etMarks);
        AddData();
    }


    //adding data to SQLite
    public void AddData() {

        btAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                System.out.println("activity: "+ etName.getText().toString() + "/ "+  etSurname.getText().toString() +"/ "+ etMarks.getText().toString());

                // checking if true or false using DatabaseHelper
                boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(etName.getText().toString(), etSurname.getText().toString(), etMarks.getText().toString());
                if (isInserted == true) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

The values are getting correctly. Any help would be appreciated but when im testing it, it will force close the app then return error log:


> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                                     at
> com.xperiasola.philubiq64wi.xperiasola.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:34)
>                                                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3574)
>                                                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14293)
>                                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
>                                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>                                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
>                                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                                                                     at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
>                                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
>                                                                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any suggestion guys? TIA :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you declared DatabaseHelper myDb but never initialized it. Probably that's why myDb is showing null. Initialize the object like this, myDb = new DatabaseHelper();

Comment: i remove the code then rebuild but error logs are the same :(

Comment: you declared DatabaseHelper myDb but never initialized it. Probably that's why myDb is showing null. Inilialize the object like this,

myDb = new DatabaseHelper();

Comment: Thanks bro sorry for a very noob mistake. It works now :)

Comment: can you give an upvote to my answer, please if it helped you in someway.

Answer (score 1):

For the constructor of `DatabaseHelper.java`, you have:

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

But the variables `name, factory, version` are unused. So I would suggest to change the constructor to:

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

In `MainActivty.java`, the `DatabaseHelper myDb` is not initialized before used. That's why you are getting `main java.lang.NullPointerException` exception.
You can initialized it inside `onCreate()`, before calling `AddData()` that install `onClickListener` to your Button.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    .....

    this.myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    AddData();
}
```

Comment: I forgot to initialize   this.myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);. Thanks guys :)